# Android webview microphone capture issue

Tags: android, audio, webview, web-audio-api, webchromeclient

I am trying to record audio using an app that runs WebView. For example, I load the app in the URL https://online-voice-recorder.com/ and records some audio over the mic. I have given enough permissions and able to record and replay the audio. On Windows 10, it works perfectly. But on my Android Oreo 8.1.0 running Chrom version 80, this audio is fully distorted. I tested it another device and the audio is partially legible.

Is this a standard behavior?

What I have tried to see what is the problem: I wrote a backend netcore3.1 app to play the audio and it plays the same distorted sound.

I have also tried using default sampling rates and custom and in either case, the audio remains distorted.

Comment: Seems like a bug with chrome/android. Can you post an audio file of the recording? It might give some hints on what's wrong

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/whatsappaudio2020-04-13at124310pm @JensV

Comment: Did you test it with a native audio recorder app? Is the audio quality good there?

Comment: @JensV, yes native audio is perfectly working